# Git authentication with windows service

Tags: c#, windows, git, authentication, windows-services

I have a windows service written in C#. I want to set the service account to be LocalSystem. The service spawns a process which is a batch file in which Git Authentication is required. If I set the service account as User, it prompts for username and password while installation and the service runs perfectly. But when I register it as LocalSystem account, it fails to do so.
Event Viewer error log is:

```
Source: Git Credential Manager
Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
```

The reason I want to go with LocalSystem account is I want to avoid any credential pop-up. Any help on how I can install the service without any password pop-up and authenticate git as well as current logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a prompt for credentials, you need to set up a credential helper properly.  It's likely that you are indeed using one, in this case the Git Credential Manager for Windows, but in this case that requires a UI prompt.

You will first need to make sure the system Git installation does not use a credential helper by typing `git config --system --unset credential.helper`.  Then, configure your service to use an appropriate `credential.helper` argument when you're invoking your push or fetch command, like so: `git -c credential.helper=my-credential-helper push origin main`.

You can either write your own credential helper by following the directions in the `gitcredentials(7)` manual page and specify that name or use a shell command to get it from the environment.  For example, if you wanted to push code and read data from the `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` environment variables, then you'd run this command:

```
$ git -c credential.helper='f() { echo username=$USERNAME; echo password=$PASSWORD; };f' \
    push origin main
```